# Как называется одним словом членение текста на абзацы?

Tags: выбор-слов, терминология, редактура, оформление-текста

Дается полностью слитый в одно месиво текст.
Его надо поделить на абзацы.
Как называется это деление?

Comment: Если вам дали полезный ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 6):

Так и называется - абзацное членение.

А одним словом членение на отрезки называется фрагментацией, но это не абзацное членение, а выделение цветом или шрифтом нужных отрезков.

Answer (score 3):

Есть филологический термин - **абзацирование**, встречается в разных научных трудах, монографиях и т.п. Например ["Абзацирование научного текста: На материале нередактирован. рукописей"](http://www.dslib.net/russkij-jazyk/abzacirovanie-nauchnogo-teksta-na-materiale-neredaktirovan-rukopisej.html).

Comment: Спасибо, здорово! Мне этот термин никогда ранее не встречался.

Comment: Мне тоже. Чаще всё-таки говорят "абзацное членение". Если честно, термин  абзацирование воспринимается как что-то заумное, его даже Ворд подчёркивает. Но раз в науке встречается, вопросов нет.